# How do I UV unwrap multiple objects to one UV map?

Tags: uv

I have created a model in blender consisting of many cubes. Now instead of UV unwrapping every single cube, how can I UV unwrap all cubes together to one UV map?

Comment: You can join them all into one object, map it and Separate by loose parts to get individual cubes back.

Comment: You can join them with CTRL+J when you have them all selected.

Comment: Try the texture atlas addon - you can find several tutorials on youtube for it.

Answer (score 7):

The best way IMO would be using the ***Texture Atlas*** add on as joining meshes is sometimes destructive (think you have different modifier for each object- as in my example pictured below).

Enable the add on in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

Select all your objects in *Object Mode*, go to the *Render* header-->*Texture Atlas* panel and press the ***'+'*** button, then *OK*. Next press ***Start Manual Unwrap*** button. Enter *Edit Mode*, go to the *UV Editor*, select all islands (<kbd>A</kbd>) and pack them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). Now you have all the objects' maps combined in one *UV Map*. Finally press ***Finish Manual Unwrap*** button to separate objects.
[image]

Comment: It depends on whether he wants cubes to use the same texture / mapping (my anwser) or to have independent map (your anwser).